# function to validate dates from a list and return a tuple with findings

Tags: python

I need help to create a function that receives the 2 values below and returns a tuple with 2 lists inside as detailed below.

```
initial_date = date(2021, 11, 30)
today = date.today()
balance_dates = {
    1: date(2020, 5, 31), 2: date(2020, 6, 20), 3: date(2020, 6, 20),
    4: date(2020, 8, 30), 5: date(2020, 5, 31), 6: date(2020, 12, 31),
    7: date(2020, 5, 31), 8: date(2020, 11, 30), 9: date(2023, 2, 28),
    10: date(2024, 5, 31), 11: date(2023, 11, 30), 12: date(2023, 2, 28),
```

}

**Function:** check_missing_or_wrong_balances(initial_date, balance_date) (**Returns a tuple** with 2 lists)

**Description of the tuple**:

1. (list 1) Check if `balance_date` has at least one date representing the very last day of each month from `initial_date` to the current date and if not, create/append the missing month (full date with the last day YYY-mm-dd) to a list and return it as the first value of the tuple.
2. (list 2) if the date tested above isn't the last day of the given month, create/append the id of that date in another list returned as the second value of the tuple. Additionally, add the ids of future dates (after the current date) and ids of duplicated dates, leaving only the first match found outside of this (e.g. if 3 exact dates were found, add the id of 2 occurences).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Mushroomator I'm sure what is the correct way to do this. While I'm posting this to see better ideas from more experienced people, I'm trying to generate a list with monthrange() with all the correct end of months and then compare with the list given in the argument. Also use standard functions to deduplicate values in a list and a for to check for future dates at the end. but this seems too much and maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: @Pabluez I've Edited my answer check it again.

Comment: If you have working code, try asking in [codereview.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation of the check_missing_or_wrong_balances function that satisfies the requirements described:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def check_missing_or_wrong_balances(initial_date, balance_date):
    # Convert the initial date to a datetime object
    initial_date = datetime.strptime(initial_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

    # Create a list of expected end-of-month dates from the initial date to now
    today = datetime.now()
    expected_dates = []
    while initial_date <= today:
        year = initial_date.year
        month = initial_date.month
        last_day = (datetime(year, month, 1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
        expected_dates.append(last_day)
        initial_date = last_day + timedelta(days=1)

    # Create two lists to store the results
    missing_dates = []
    wrong_dates = []

    # Loop through the balance dates and process each one
    processed_dates = set() # Set to keep track of already processed dates
    for id, date_str in balance_date.items():
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        if date in processed_dates:
            continue # Skip already processed dates
        processed_dates.add(date)
        if date > today:
            wrong_dates.append(id)
            continue
        if date not in expected_dates:
            missing_dates.append((date.year, date.month, date.day))
        else:
            expected_dates.remove(date)
        last_day = (date + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
        if date != last_day:
            wrong_dates.append(id)

    # Check if there are any remaining expected dates not found in balance_date
    for date in expected_dates:
        missing_dates.append((date.year, date.month, date.day))

    # Return the results as a tuple of two lists
    return (missing_dates, wrong_dates)
```

Here's how you can use this function with the example data you provided:

```
initial_date = "1985-05-31"
balance_date = {
    '1': '2020-05-31', '2': '2020-06-20', '3': '2020-06-20',
    '4': '2020-08-30', '5': '2020-05-31', '6': '2020-12-31',
    '7': '2020-05-31', '8': '2020-11-30', '9': '2023-02-29',
    '10': '2024-05-31', '11': '2023-11-30', '12': '2023-02-28',
}

missing_dates, wrong_dates = check_missing_or_wrong_balances(initial_date, balance_date)
print("Missing dates:", missing_dates)
print("Wrong dates:", wrong_dates)
```